# C# Inheritance - Differentiating Derived-Object From Base-Object

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class, ienumerator

In an inventory program, I have made classes `Item` and `ItemCollection`, as well as a derived class `Computer : Item`.

In a form, I create an `ItemCollection` (a generic list of `Item`s) called `TheseItems` (including some Computers) and I want to display the properties of each item `ThisItem` (like location, quantity, etc.).

While doing this, I want to also display distinct properties for computers (such as CPU, HDD, and RAM). I have this so far:

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)

    if (ThisItem is Computer)
    {
        //Display distinct properties of Computer instance “ThisItem”
    }
}
```

So far, there are no errors, but I’m not sure how to proceed. Is it possible to do what I want?

EDIT: Thanks, steak! I was worried that casting wouldn't allow me to access pre-assigned properties (and merely allow the to assign new ones), but I was fortunately mistaken! I now have:

```
Computer ThisComputer = ThisItem as Computer;
if (Computer != null)
{
     //Display distinct properties of Computer instance “ThisComputer”
}
```

I'm really impressed with the quick help I received. Thanks!

Comment: What you have will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work.

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)

    if (ThisItem is Computer)
    {
        Computer computerItem = (Computer)ThisItem;
        //Display distinct properties of Computer instance “ThisItem”
    }
}
```

Or use the `as` keyword for a slight optimization:

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)
    var computerItem = ThisItem as Computer;
    if (computerItem != null)
    {
        //Display distinct properties of Computer instance “ThisItem”
    }
}
```

Also, a friend of mine wrote a nice utility class to helps with this.  I thought I'd post it since it's turned out to be very useful.

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)
    ThisItem.Match()
            .Case<Computer>(comp => /* Do stuff with your computer */)
            .Case<Television>(tv => /* Do stuff with your television */)
            .Default(item => /* Do stuff with your item */);
}
```

The utility class looks something like this.  Below gives the gist, and it's very expandable.

```
public class Matcher<TMatch>
{
    private readonly TMatch _matchObj;
    private bool _isMatched;

    public Matcher(TMatch matchObj)
    {
        this._matchObj = matchObj;
    }

    public Matcher<TMatch> Case<TCase>(Action<TCase> action) where TCase : TMatch
    {
        if(this._matchObj is TCase)
        {
            this.DoCase(() => action((TCase)this._matchObj));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Default(Action<TMatch> action)
    {
        this.DoCase(() => action(this._matchObj));
    }

    private void DoCase(Action action)
    {
        if (!this._isMatched)
        {
            action();
            this._isMatched = true;
        }
    }
}

public static class MatcherExtensions
{
    public static Matcher<TMatch> Match<TMatch>(this TMatch matchObj)
    {
        return new Matcher<TMatch>(matchObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just beat me.  My answer is DITTO.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do the same thing is to have `Computer computerItem = ThisItem as Computer; if (computerItem != null) { ... }`. The `is` operator actually does an `as` operation and then checks it for `null`, so doing `is` followed by a cast actually requires an extra instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I normally use. It may be slightly faster than checking the type and then casting (I have no proof of this).

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)

    var computer = ThisItem as Computer;
    if (computer != null)
    {
         //Display distinct properties of Computer instance “ThisItem”
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell, don't ask.

Don't ask `ThisItem` for its properties so you can write them, tell it to write them for you

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    ThisItem.DisplayProperties(Console.out);
}
```

Then, make `DisplayProperties()` virtual, and overload it in `Computer` to include the properties exclusive to it.

Comment: +1 This is often the best answer for these types of problems, but not always.  It's probably even the best answer for the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just inside your IF clause, cast to your derived class and the properties will be available.

```
foreach (Item ThisItem in TheseItems)
{
    //Display properties of Item instance “ThisItem” (Excluded for ease of reading)

    if (ThisItem is Computer)
    {
       var ThisComputer = (Computer) ThisItem;
       Display(ThisComputer.CPU);
       //etc
    }
}
```